# intellij IDEA distinguish different projects by color

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working with two different intellij IDEA projects in parallel.

As the contents of these projects look quite similar, I several times do changes in the wrong project.

Is it possible to distinguish different projects by e.g. different background colors
Is it possible to distinguish different projects by e.g. different background colors in the editor window?

Comment: Do you open two different project in one intellij instance? Or have two intellijs open at the same time?

Comment: I open two different projects in one intellij instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a different [background picture](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/setting-background-image.html) for each project to distinguish them from each other. Enter <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and search for the `Set Background Image` action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows). Be sure to check the `This project only` checkbox there.

[image]

Comment: That's working perfectly. 

With a one colour background image, I can set distinguish the projects easily.

Comment: If the answer works for you please ["accept"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it

Comment: I don't think you need reputation to accept an answer. You will gain 2 points reputation when you accept an answer in fact. For voting you do need 15 points, but that is something else.

Comment: no this does not work. it shows an image across all projects

Comment: @OliverWatkins is the `This project only` checkbox checked?

Comment: ah yes. Took me a while to find it. Added screenshot for clarity